# Laravel:: php artisan migrate is not updating the changes

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan, migrate

I want to update my database with one extra column that I forgot so I dropped my database and added that field in create method and also in fillable but whenever I am migrating it. it is taking only previous fields but not adding a new one. what is the problem?

Comment: Did you add a new migration or did you just edit the first one?

Comment: I have edited first one

Comment: Good approach is just create new migration for any changes,If you use 'php artisan migrate:fresh --seed',It may result in drastic loss of data.Never do it in production.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time. I got it it is little college project hehe.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you migrated, then edit it afterwards, then Laravel wont pick up a new column.

You have to migrate fresh and seed again:

`php artisan migrate:fresh --seed` (don't do this in production)